# sharing an ext3/ext4 partition on external drive

Tags: partition, ext3, ext4, share

is there a way of sharing an ext3/ext4 formatted partition on an external USB drive between different users (uids) on different Linux machines without creating a group for this purpose, setting the group ownership of the partition to this group and adding each respective user to the group on every machine?

This would mean that I need to have root privileges on every machine... which I may not have in some cases.

I'm using the partition to store the code I'm developing on Linux and I would like the option to be safe... if possible.

I could use a vfat partition but then I have no control of the rw rights + I cannot develop directly in the dir: I would always have to tar.gz the directory, extract, work, tar.gz, copy to the external drive... and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of permissions should users have in the shared directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer is "no". uid and gid on the filesystem will be as set at the moment of the write and if they don't match on a different machine, then privileges won't match either.

If you do not want to make a small revolution with uids/gids on several machines, you could try using acls to set the desired permissions for all desired users on all machines. I suspect this will use numerical uids internally, so it could happen, that giving access to your account foo on machine A, uid a, will give access to your files to a random guy bar on machine B, uid a. It also seems like it's more hassle than it's worth.

I think that saner approach would be to use tar to migrate your development tree.

I have also had a half-baked idea of carrying around a Subversion repository (with files writable only to root and appropriate access configuration files), and relying on svn server being present on all machines which you are going to use, but I do not think it's excessively sane.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! So, the right way to go is then to use vfat as the filesystem to get around the permissions, and tar.gz my directories?

Comment: vfat/ntfs (because they will have automagically set uid to your own upon file system mount) or extN with a world-writeable directory. It is really ironic, to use Windows file system to move data between Linuxes.

Comment: "It is really ironic, to use Windows file system to move data between Linuxes." :) It's kind of sad, yes. This is why I wanted to investigate other options in the first place. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I discover that `sys` group share id `3` on Debian, Ubuntu, RedHat, Fedora, CentOS, Suse, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, MacOSX, Solaris.

No other groups name share same id. Even `root` group with id `0` on some systems actually is `wheel`. And `nogroup` on Linux is usually `65534` but on BSD is `32766` ((

Set segid bit and ACL (including default) to `sys` on directory on external storage:

```
$ sudo chgrp -R sys /mnt/data/dir
$ sudo chgmod -R g+s /mnt/data/dir
$ sudo fsetacl -R -m g:sys:rwx /mnt/data/dir
$ sudo fsetacl -R -d -m g:sys:rwx /mnt/data/dir
```

After adding `user` to `sys` group it able to read and write to `/mnt/data/dir` on any host. You no longer need `sudo` privileges each time to grand access.

`sys` group and `setgid` bit do job well, but to workaround `uname` mask you need to use ACL.

This is best what you can do.

UNIX is not designed for personal/home usage. It is corporate/enterprise OS, where is not defined plugging removable media across different hosts ((

See also:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273144/predefined-group-ids-across-linux-distros/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126213/external-hard-drive-permissions-ext4/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/12009/solving-permission-problems-when-using-external-ext4-hard-disk-with-multiple-lin/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/252361/how-could-i-mount-an-ext4-partition-and-have-write-permission/